# SharePoint Online - Powershell - "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

In my code, I am trying to load "web" after creating client context. 
Below is my code:

```
$SiteUrl  = "...."; #My site URL goes here#
    $uname =$xmlFile.Account.Trim() 
    $pwd = $xmlFile.Password.Trim()
    Add-Type -Path $path"\DLLs\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path $path"\DLLs\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
    $securePassword=New-Object SecureString
    foreach($c in $pwd.ToCharArray())
    {
        $securePassword.AppendChar($c)
    } 
    # Getting ClientContext object.. 
    $clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($uname, $pwd) 

    $clientContext.Credentials =   New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credentials)

    if (!$clientContext.ServerObjectIsNull.Value) 
    { 
       try{

            $web = $clientContext.Web;
            $clientContext.Load($web);
            $clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
            write-host $web

            }

            catch
            {

            }
    }
```

I am getting error:

> System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden." ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change the way you load the CSOM DLLs from this:

```
Add-Type -Path $path"\DLLs\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path $path"\DLLs\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
```

to this:

```
Add-Type -path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
Add-Type -path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
```

Substituting whatever the proper path to your DLLs is.

I don't understand exactly what is going on, but in my environment I have to use the full path when running the script on my server, but I don't have to on my workstation. Otherwise I get the same `(403) Forbidden` error that you do

Answer (score 0):

I think this lines are correct (compare with yours):

```
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($uname, $pwd) 
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion as well. No luck!

Comment: Please check in browser that your user\pass are valid.

Comment: Yes, its correct. Also,this same code works from one machine. But from different machine(server) its throwing error.

Comment: Can you confirm there is no proxy configuration for this machine?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below example and see how it works on your system.

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"   

$siteUrl = "site url" 
$username = "username" 
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString  

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)  
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)  
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials 

$rootWeb = $ctx.Web  
$ctx.Load($rootWeb) 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Write-Host $rootWeb.Title
```